# fast album art thumbnail handling like iTunes?

Tags: cocoa, performance, user-interface, thumbnails

Im working with a few guys on trying to develop an app that requires some thumbnail scrubbing to handle album and tv show / movie art work in a grid view..

Much like iTunes does!  But were having some trouble with getting the grid view to match the speed and agility of iTunes.

Anyone have suggestions on what to use in Cocoa UI world to make this better or more like iTunes?

See video for comparison...first our app then iTunes...

https://files.me.com/teemujin/0l0bc7.mov

IF you were to build an iTunes clone... how would you go about it?

Comment: Did you profile it in Instruments and see where all that time between redraws was going?

Comment: yea we ended up getting rid of a ton of instances of view and replacing them with draw rect instead... now its working a lot better. Lessons learned..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too many instances of view... switched to draw rect and reduced those instances till the redraw for scaling and scrolling was much improved.